# Why is my array being overwritten?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, date, element

I am using node.js for a project and I am trying to add certain dates to an array. However, when I do, it overwrites the entire array with the current date being added. Source below:

```
let startDate = new Date(2014, 0, 8, 19, 0, 0)
let endDate = new Date(2014, 0, 11, 19, 0, 0)
let datesToDownload = []
let datesInDB = [new Date(2014, 0, 8, 19, 0, 0), new Date(2014, 0, 9, 19, 0, 0), new Date(2014, 0, 10, 19, 0, 0), new Date(2014, 0, 8, 11, 0, 0)]

for (let i = startDate; i <= endDate; i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1)) {
  console.log('CHECKING DATE: ' + i.toDateString())

  if (!(datesInDB2.indexOf(i.toDateString()) >= 0)) {
    console.log('NEW RECORD FOUND FOR: ' + i.toDateString())
    datesToDownload.push(i)
    console.log('i: ' + i)

    for (let j in datesToDownload) {
      console.log('element ' + j + ': ' + datesToDownload[j])
    }
  }
}
```

And the output looks like this:

```
CHECKING DATE: Wed Jan 08 2014
NEW RECORD FOUND FOR: Wed Jan 03 2014

i: Wed Jan 08 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
element 0: Wed Jan 08 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

CHECKING DATE: Thur Jan 09 2016
NEW RECORD FOUND FOR: Thur Jan 09 2016

i: Thur Jan 09 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
element 0: Thur Jan 09 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
element 1: Thur Jan 09 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

CHECKING DATE: Fri Jan 10 2016
NEW RECORD FOUND FOR: Fri Jan 10 2016

i: Fri Jan 10 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
element 0: Fri Jan 10 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
element 1: Fri Jan 10 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
element 2: Fri Jan 10 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

......
```

Notice how the elements are all changed to the current date being inserted, though an element is being added.

Why is this happening? How can I prevent it?

Comment: All the inserted `Date` objects are actually the same object, you are just creating an array of references to a `Date` object that keeps getting modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pushing exactly the same Date instance into the array on each iteration. You can create a *copy* of it however:

```
  datesToDownload.push(new Date(i));
```

Comment: @Pointy I see. Is this common in other languages or is this specifically an issue in JavaScript?

Comment: @AmishJohn81 this would happen in some other languages, yes. It's pretty common for object references to be passed as parameter values rather than object copies.

Answer (score 2):

A date is an object, and is passed by reference. In your for loop you are changing the date:

```
for (let i = startDate; i <= endDate; i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1)) {
```

Comment: That ended abruptly. It's _obvious_ he is changing the value of `i`, that was the intention, but this explains nothing about why the end result is the same everywhere.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but he was on the right path for sure.